# Как создать массив Image из картинки 1024 на 768 (C#)

Tags: c#, изображения, bitmap, tile

Цель Создать на C# `Image[,]`. Разобрать одну большую картинку на много маленьких и закинуть в двумерный массив. Размер тайла 32/32. Размер источника 1024/768.

Comment: А с чем у вас проблема? Покажите, что вы пытались.

Comment: Пытался вообще вывести картинку произвольной области чтобы пройти циклом.            BitMap   bmp = загружаю картинку с ресурсов
            // прямоугольник-источник
            Rectangle rSrc = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);                 //прямоугольник-адресат
            Rectangle rDest = new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32);
            // вывод изображения попиксельно
           graph.DrawImage(bmp, rDest, rSrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну, например так (для WPF):

```
var uri = new Uri(fullPath);
var originalBmp = new BitmapImage(uri);

var m = 1024 / 32;
var n = 768 / 32;

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    var rect = new Int32Rect() { X = i * 32, Y = j * 32, Width = 32, Height = 32 };
    result[i, j] = new CroppedBitmap(originalBmp, rect);
}
```

---

Для WinForms используется System.Drawing.Bitmap:

```
using (var stream = ...)
using (var originalBmp = new Bitmap(stream))
{
    var m = 1024 / 32;
    var n = 768 / 32;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(i * 32, j * 32, 32, 32);
        result[i, j] = originalBmp.Clone(rect, originalBmp.PixelFormat);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что координаты в `Rectangle` **не имеют права** вылазить за границу исходной картинки, иначе [вы получите (достаточно непонятное) исключение: `OutOfMemoryException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/654861/276994).

Comment: а как тоже самое для WinForms

Comment: @Igorenzia: Сейчас напишу.

Comment: @Igorenzia: подправил

Comment: Bitmap[,] result = new Bitmap[1000, 1000];
            try
            {

                using (var originalBmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._1))
                {
                    var m = 1024 / 32;
                    var n = 768 / 32;

                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                        {
                            var rect = new Rectangle(i * 32, j * 32, 32, 32);
                            result[i, j] = originalBmp.Clone(rect, originalBmp.PixelFormat);
                        }

Comment: Exception  недостаточно памяти

Comment: @Igorenzia Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, сославшись на этот для предоставления контекста.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. (ошибка была в размерах исходной картинки)

Comment: @Igorenzia: Угу, добавил в ответ. Пожалуйста!